# Ember direct route dont loads content

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have this route

```
this.resource('todos', { path: '/todos' }, function() {
  this.route('todo', { path: '/todo/:todo_id' });
  this.route('new', {path: '/todo/new'});
});
```

And here is the controller for the route todo

```
App.TodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Todo.find(params.todo_id);
  }
});
```

When I go load directly /todos, and then select a todo is loaded as expected, but when I try to load a todo directly /todo/idOfTheTodoHere, nothign is loaded.

I have to add something to the controller for wait till all the data is found to load the template ?

I will put here full route

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('app', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route("about");

    this.resource('todos', { path: '/todos' }, function() {
      this.route('todo', { path: '/todo/:todo_id' });
      this.route('new', {path: '/todo/new'});
    });
  });
});

//This works and finds All todos
App.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Todo.find();
  }
});

App.TodosNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Todo.create;
  }
});

App.TodosTodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(App.Todo.find();
    return Todo.find(params.todo_id);
  }
});
```

Now when I go to /#/routes all todos are displayed correctly, and I can create a new one, but when I click on a single todo for display it and the route changes to /#/todos/todo/ID, if I relaod the browser the template shows nothing, looks like load directly a model on a route is returning nothing. The only param that finds is the id, the other attributes are null.

So in the template todo if I have this attributes

```
{{id}} - {{title}}
```

Only displays the id and if I check the console

```
 model: function(params) {
    console.log(App.Todo.find();
```

Return the model id, and the other values are undefined

Comment: Forgot to mention I use an ember adapter, I think the bug here is the adapter is not doing the findOne query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is it, but perhaps you mean to navigate to `#/todos/todo/SOME_ID` instead of `#/todo/SOME_ID` -- the path you provide for the todo route when you map it (`this.route('todo' {path: 'todo/:todo_id'});`) gets **appended** to the parent path (`/todos`) so you end up with `todos/todo/:todo_id`.

Besides that, you can do some debugging steps to further isolate the problem

1. Is the `model` hook of your route getting called at all?
2. Is `params.todo_id` what you expect it to be?
3. Is the browser making the correct ajax request? (to the correct endpoint)
4. Is your server responding properly to that ajax request?

**EDIT**

I think you mean to call App.Todo.find in side your model hook for the TodosTodoRoute:

```
App.TodosTodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      console.log(App.Todo.find();
      return Todo.find(params.todo_id);   // --- should be App.Todo.Find
  }
});
```

There are also a few syntax errors in the code you posted -- could you post a JSBin or JSFiddle sample that duplicates the problem?

Did you confirm that App.Todo.find(some_id) makes a request to the correct server endpoint? Is your server providing the correct response?

Comment: When I go to #/todos all the todos are there, so model and controller works. But when I copy paste #/todos/todo/SOME_ID to other tab, or reload the browser when Im on #/todos/todo/SOME_ID renders nothing.

Comment: I think this is not called 

App.TodosTodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(App.Todo.find(params.todo_id));
    return App.Todo.find(params.todo_id);
  }
});

Comment: Right, it should be called TodosTodoRoute (Todos is the resource, Todo is the route). Did that fix it? Did you see if ```find(params.todo_id) is getting called?```

Comment: I modified The route and now params is called, but returns null on all the values

Comment: What do you mean "returns null on all values" - do you mean params is an empty object? Or that Todo.find(params.todo_id) returns null? In the first case, could you post your full source code for your router + routes? It seems like a very simple routing problem if the id isn't getting serialized.

Comment: Updated with more info